# Create an multi array in C#?

Tags: c#, php

this is an example of some PHP code that I have written:

```
$list=array();
    for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
    {
        $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);
            for($hour = 1;$hour <=23; $hour++){
                $list[$hour]["0001-0010"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0011-0020"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0021-0030"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0031-0040"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0041-0050"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0051-0059"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATA"]= array();

                $list[$hour]["0001-0010"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0011-0020"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0021-0030"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0031-0040"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0041-0050"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
                $list[$hour]["0051-0059"][date('Y-m-d', $time)]["ATD"]= array();
            }
    }
```

How do you convert this to C#?

Comment: You're looking for the `Dictionary<>` class.

Comment: are you sure on that, i'm not a PHP user but that looks like an array of arrays rather than an key value indexed pairing?

Comment: @MikeT To my knowledge, PHP is the only Problem Child that thinks a string-associative collection is the same thing as an "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is quite easy using LINQ

```
from day in Enumerable.Range(1,31)
select from hour in Enumerable.Range(1,23)
       select from minute in Enumerable.Range(0,5)
              select new string[]{
                  new {string.Format("{0}(1)0-{0}{1}9 {2}-{3}-{4}ATA",hour,minute,Year,Month,day)},
                  new {string.Format("{0}(1)0-{0}{1}9 {2}-{3}-{4}ATD",hour,minute,Year,Month,day)}
              }
```

the longer method would be almost identical to your code

```
var list=new Arraylist();
for(int d=1; d<=31; d++)
{
    var daylist=new Arraylist();
    var time=new DateTime(year, month, d, 12,0,0);
    for(int hour = 1;hour <=23; hour++){
        daylist.Add(hour + "0001-0010"+time.ToString()+"ATA"]);
        daylist.Add(hour + "0011-0020"+time.ToString()+"ATA"]);
        //..etc
    }
    list.Add(daylist);
}
```

please note code is for example purpose only and is not likely to run as is

EDIT: Assuming  SLaks comment on what you are after is correct
then the above example changes to

```
var list=new Dictionary<string,object>();
for(int d=1; d<=31; d++)
{
    var time=new DateTime(year, month, d, 12,0,0);
    for(int hour = 1;hour <=23; hour++){
        list.Add(hour + "0001-0010"+time.ToString()+"ATA", value);
        list.Add(hour + "0011-0020"+time.ToString()+"ATA", value);
        //..etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I Google exactly your title, the first result is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx.

For example:

> The following declaration creates an array of three dimensions, 4, 2, and 3.

```
int[, ,] array1 = new int[4, 2, 3];
```